# find by _id with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble with a simple findById with mongoose.

Confirmed the item exists in the DB

```
db.getCollection('stories').find({_id:'572f16439c0d3ffe0bc084a4'})
```

With mongoose

```
  Story.findById(topic.storyId, function(err, res) {
    logger.info("res", res);
    assert.isNotNull(res);
  });
```

won't find it.

I also tried converting to a mongoId, still cannot be found (even though mongoose supposedly does this for you)

```
var mid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(storyId);
let story = await Story.findOne({_id: mid}).exec();
```

I'm actually trying to use this with typescript, hence the await.

I also tried the `Story.findById(id)` method, still cannot be found.

Is there some gotcha to just finding items by a plain `_id` field?
does the _id have to be in the Schema? (docs say no)

I can find by other values in the Schema, just `_id` can't be used...

---

update: I wrote a short test for this.

```
describe("StoryConvert", function() {


  it("should read a list of topics", async function test() {
    let topics = await Topic.find({});

    for (let i = 0; i < topics.length; i ++) {
      let topic = topics[i];
    // topics.forEach( async function(topic) {
      let storyId = topic.storyId;
      let mid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(storyId);
      let story = await Story.findOne({_id: mid});
      // let story = await Story.findById(topic.storyId).exec();
      // assert.equal(topic.storyId, story._id);
      logger.info("storyId", storyId);
      logger.info("mid", mid);
      logger.info("story", story);
      Story.findOne({_id: storyId}, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
        } else {
          logger.info("no error");
        }
        logger.info("res1", res);
      });

      Story.findOne({_id: mid}, function(err, res) {
        logger.info("res2", res);
      });

      Story.findById(mid, function(err, res) {
        logger.info("res3", res);
        // assert.isNotNull(res);
      });

    }

  });


});
```

It will return stuff like

```
Testing storyId 572f16439c0d3ffe0bc084a4

Testing mid 572f16439c0d3ffe0bc084a4

Testing story null

Testing no error

Testing res1 null

Testing res2 null

Testing res3 null
```

I noticed that `topic.storyId` is a string
not sure if that would cause any issues mapping to the other table.
I tried also adding some type defs

```
  storyId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: false
  }
```

[image]

Comment: _id is created by default No need to add it in schema
Are you able to retrieve records? if so when using that _id try to covert it into toObject().
I Am not sure give it a try!!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because this query finds the doc in the shell:

```
db.getCollection('stories').find({_id:'572f16439c0d3ffe0bc084a4'})
```

That means that the type of `_id` in the document is actually a string, not an `ObjectId` like Mongoose is expecting.

To find that doc using Mongoose, you'd have to define `_id` in the schema for `Story` as:

```
_id: { type: String }
```

Comment: this sounds like the right situation. I am migrating some data across that was created before we started using mongo, so the types are probably inconsistent. I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: this was the issue, and well spotted that the basic shell query (not using an ObjectId) was working, so that was the give-away.

Comment: also works on mongoose, `const modelSchema = new Schema({ _id: { type: String } }, { strict: false });`

Answer (score 8):

If your Mongo schema is configured to use Object Id, you query in nodeJS using

`models.Foo.findById(id)`

where **Foo** is your model and **id** is your id.
here's a working example

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id
    models.Foo.findById(id)        
        .lean().exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
        try {
            console.log(results)            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("errror getting results")
            console.log(error)
        } 
    })
})
```

In Mongo DB your query would be

```
{_id:ObjectId('5c09fb04ff03a672a26fb23a')}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use mongoose.ObjectId()

```
const Model = require('./model')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

Model.find({ id: mongoose.ObjectId(userID) })
```

It works, but it is weird because we are using id instead of _id

Comment: yup, simple and easiest!

Answer (score 1):

If _id is the default mongodb key, in your model set the type of _id as this:

```
_id: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId
```

Then usind mongoose you can use a normal find:

```
YourModel.find({"_id": "5f9a86b77676e180c3089c3d"});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it now:

```
const { mongoose } = require("mongoose");
YourModel.find({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("572f16439c0d3ffe0bc084a4") });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got into this scenario too. This was how I solved it;

- According to the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find), you need to tell mongoose to
  return the raw js objects, not mongoose documents by passing the `lean` option and setting it to true. e.g

```sh
Adventure.findById(id, 'name', { lean: true }, function (err, doc) {});
```

in your situation, it would be

```sh
Story.findById(topic.storyId, { lean: true }, function(err, res) {
    logger.info("res", res);
    assert.isNotNull(res);
});
```

Comment: A bit OT but `Adventure` and `Story` sound interesting. are you making an adventure game engine?

Answer (score 0):

For usage with Schema and _id default mongo Key. Set the typeof _id in the Schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    //Add another field
});
 

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
module.exports.ProjectsService = class ProjectsService {

    async getProjectById(req, res) {
        try {
            const projectId = req.params.projectId;             
            let project = await Project.find({ "_id": projectId })
            res.json(project);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
models.findById(id)
```

TRY THIS ONE .
REF LINK : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mongoose-findbyid-function/

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 Story.findOne({_id:"572b19509dac77951ab91a0b"}, function(err, story){
                if (err){
                    console.log("errr",err);
                    //return done(err, null);
                }else{
                    console.log(story);
                }

 });
```

Comment: any error or use id proper id that exist in your db