# How to use _id in mongoose's findOneAndUpdate filter?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I found [find by _id with Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347802/find-by-id-with-mongoose) after not being able to use `findOneAndUpdate` by setting an `_id` in the filter. The answer says I must define it in the Schema. If I put _id in the schema, I get

```
Error [MongooseError]: document must have an _id before saving
```

which I agree. It's Mongo who should set the Id.

So how can I use _id in `findOneAndUpdate`?

**UPDATE:**

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    deleted: Boolean,
    client: {
        name: String,
        phone: String
    },
    products: [{
        name: String,
        quantity: Number,
        price: Number
    }],
    seller_id: Number,
    order_id: Number,
    total: Number
});
```

I want to update it using

```
let r = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: idExample, seller_id: json.seller_id }, order);
```

however it complains there's no `_id` with `idExample`. The answer in [find by _id with Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347802/find-by-id-with-mongoose) tells me to use `_id: String` in the schema, but then I get `Error [MongooseError]: document must have an _id before saving`

Comment: Can you give us the code which uses `findOneAndUpdate` & failing, Please add request/actual documents in DB as well..

Comment: @srinivasy I updated. Can you take a look?

Comment: what do you get back with this `Order.findOne({ _id: idExample, seller_id: json.seller_id })` - are you able to get a document to `null` ?

Comment: Definitely you do not need to specify `_id` field in the schema, especially not if its `string`, i think your problem is `order` in the update section, what is it?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?